# The impact of not creating indexes

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm creating a table using this script.

```
create table TimeFrames(
  Id int identity,
  Name varchar(100),
  Active bit
)
```

Before, I also altered the table by adding a primary key and anindex. However, now, I've forgotten to do the latter and, since I experience no difference in functionality, I wonder if it's only because of performance considerations that it needs to be there.

```
alter table TimeFrames add constraint PkTimeFrames primary key (Id)
create clustered index IxTimeFramesId on dbo.TimeFrames(Id)
```

Are there other considerations regarding the index?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You did create the primary key, right?

Indexes are there for performance reasons, unless they are also unique.  In that case, they require each record to have a different value/set of values for the affected columns.

A clustered index will also determine how the rows are physically stored in the database, but that probably also falls under "performance".

Comment: I create the primary key as shown in the table alteration. I don't quite understand the part of indexes being unique, though. Aren't all indexes **by definition** unique?

Comment: No, actually they aren't!  You can have a non-unique index over a column or set of columns.  That speeds up finding records by the values in those columns, but doesn't constrain what data you can add or how you can change a record.

Comment: Aha! The same way the last two digits of the phone numbers in a catalog would index all of them but **not uniquely** reference! Didn't think of that. +1 for explanation.

Answer (score 2):

Indexes exist almost exclusively for performance reasons.  The one major exception that I can readily think of are unique indexes.  These are also used to enforce `unique` constraints.

There is also the issue that a `foreign key` constraint requires a unique or primary key constraint in the referenced table.

Comment: I'm using primary keys as foreign keys in other tables. The data load is limited so performance isn't an issue. However, I'm not clear on the indexes not being unique. How can an index not be unique?

Comment: @KonradViltersten . . . A "unique" index is one that guarantees that the key values are not duplicated.  A regular index does not have this additional condition.

Answer (score 2):

Indexes support queries and to enforce some table constraints. If you have a 'write-only' table then indexes probably aren't going to help you very much. Those are rare in my experience.

Answer (score 2):

As the other posts have stated, Indexes are mainly used for performance reasons.

[Here is a blog post](http://blog.copadata.at/wp/pros-and-cons-of-using-sql-server-table-indices) explaining the Pros and Cons of using them.

**Query and Stored Procedure Performance**

As the table grows in size, the amount of data that needs to be read to find the information will be a lot less if an index is applied. If no index is applied then the whole table needs to be read to find the data.

**Insert Performance**

As insert operations in the table also have to update the index, the insert performance might be reduced after creating indices on the table.

**Space Requirements**

As indices are additional information about a data table, they require some space to store the information.

**Index Maintenance**

Both internal and external fragmentation have an impact on the performance of the table. Take a look at the recommendations for when and how to reorganize an index. SQL will automatically update index statistics on every reorganization and rebuild.

SQL Server uses Index Statistics to decide whether an index should be used.

Comment: You might want to summarize in a few bullet items what the blog says. I'm going to read the blog as well, of course, but StackOverflow encourages replies that are not link-only, in case the external blogs/resources move or disappear.

Comment: Taken on board, I will get the answer amended to include a brief description of the post. Thanks

Comment: Do that, please, and a nice +1 is waiting for you.   :)

Comment: Would you say that is a much better answer?